# type hints (warnings) for python in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting

I enjoy using type hinting (annotation) and have used it for some time to help write clean code.

I appreciate that they are just hints and as such do not affect the code.

But today I saw a video **where the linter picked up the hint** with a warning (a squiggly yellow underline), which looks really helpful. My editor ('vscode') does not pick this up in the linter.

Here is an image of what i expect (with annotations):

[image]

So my question is, how can i achieve this ?

(For example, is there a specific linter or setting that would do this?)

Comment: have you installed a linter? Linters do not operate on unsaved files, on hover PyLance shows the type of a variable but it is up to you to honor it.

Comment: @rioV8,  the **warnings do operate on unsaved files**.  In the example, the file was not saved and an error was picked up (can see the file is not saved via the white dot next to the file name).

Comment: but they are from PyLance the language server, it handles the completion items so it must analyze unsaved files, external linters do only work on saved files, PyLance is NOT a linter

Comment: @rioV8,  appreciated, but that does not answer the question. **How to get warnings for failed python hints in vscode ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Pylance, you can add a new line to your `settings.json` (you need to restart VS Code after updating the file):

```
"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic"
```

The default value is `off`, the other possible values are `basic` and `strict`.

The following screenshot shows warnings for different situations: wrong variable type, wrong function return type and wrong parameter type.

[image]

Comment: I do use `pylance`, so keenly tried this, but it does not return the desired result, which is to flag up (with a yellow underscore) where a hint is not correctly adhered to...  can you show that it work for you ?

Comment: I just added a screenshot showing the result after updating the settings. I believe it matches what you are expecting. Did you restart VS Code after updating `settings.json`?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i am seeking.  I changed the settings `python.analysis.typeCheckingMode` to `basic` and did a restart, but did not get this...  i did this from the settings option as opposed to appending `settings.json`...  would that be why ?

Comment: editing the `settings.json` file worked !  editing the settings from the command pallet did not. . . .   Thank you.  I have marked this as the correct answer as it completely resolved the problem.